# How to disable the ActiveSync synchronization setup wizard?

Tags: windows-mobile, activesync

In my team we share the different windows mobile devices we use for testing during development. This means that every time you plug in a device, ActiveSync creates a pop-up for the "Synchronization setup wizard". I'm looking for a way to disable this wizard and connect the phone as "Guest" without having to look around for any irritating pop-ups.

Answer (score 3):

Wherever you are using Activesync or Mobile Device Centre for Vista

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows CE Services]

"GuestOnly"=dword:00000001
```

This will ensure only Guest Only connections

Answer (score -1):

In your windows mobile. You can choose what to do when it is connected to the pc.

Start -> Settings -> Connections -> USB to PC

Choose the best option to suit your need. You can disable ActiveSync auto startup there.

Comment: The options in there does not seem to do the trick. I can only choose between Active sync and Storage unit mode. And it doesn't allow me to change to Storage unit since I doesn't have a memory card. The options left are "Activate advanced network functionality" and "Ask which connection type to use when connecting". These options seem to make no difference to the wizard popping up.